# Rails: slow partial rendering when cache_classes is false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm upgrading a Rails 3.2 application up to version 5. The first thing that I'm doing is to upgrade to version 4 and make all tests are still passing.

One thing that I noticed is that my application is now very slow in development mode. Some requests are taking 1500ms when they used to take less than 50ms in 3.2.

After some debugging I found that if I enable cache_classes configuration in version 4, I will get a similar performance to the one that I used to have in version 3.2 with cache_classes disabled.

**Rails 4.2.9 ( config.cache_classes = false )**

```
(previous render messages intentionally removed )
  Rendered application/_row.html.erb (91.2ms)
  Rendered application/_row.html.erb (104.1ms)
  Rendered application/_row.html.erb (103.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1617ms (Views: 1599.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
```

**Rails 4.2.9 ( config.cache_classes = true )**

```
(previous render messages intentionally removed )
  Rendered application/_row.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered application/_row.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered application/_row.html.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 41.8ms | ActiveRecord: 7.7ms
```

From what I was able to check, when config.cache_classes = false, partials and classes aren't cached by Rails anymore. Not even in the same request like they used to be in 3.2.

I also checked config.reload_classes_only_on_change which seemed pertinent and it's set to true.

Is there something else that I should check/change to get a similar to the one that I used to have in 3.2 with cache_classes disabled? Or is it a regression in Rails that can't be fixed?

Unfortunately developing with cache_classes enabled isn't viable.

Note 1: I created an empty rails 4.2.9 and was able to reproduce this issue by creating a lot of partials and enabling/disabling cache_classes.

Note 2: The same issue seems to happen in Rails 5. I'm focusing in Rails 4 because that's the one that I'm working now.